# How I can enable debug mode for Fireabase crashlytics at my emulator?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I see that sometimes I don't receive a crash report at my dashboard. And I would like to enable DEBUG mode. As I see I have to write some commands to my ADB shell, but when I write it the shell doesn't recognize them:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.Fabric DEBUG
adb shell setprop log.tag.CrashlyticsCore DEBUG
```

Where do I have to write these lines for enabling Firebase Debug mode?

Answer (score 1):

**Add into App level Gradle**

```
android {
 signingConfigs {
        key {
            keyAlias 'yourkeyalies'
            keyPassword 'password'
            storeFile file('D:\\your_path\\projectkeystore.jks')
            storePassword 'password'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.key
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: and this will enable crashlytics mode?